# SQL Server Agent Job monitoring and notification

Tags: sql-server, email, sql-server-agent, sql-agent-job

I want to create a stored procedure/ Job that will monitor all the SQL server Agent job. When any of the SQL Server Agent's jobs fail it will send and email with the job name to the admin.

What is the best way to create such a job that will monitor all jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this issue in several ways. From top of my head you can use either a SSRS report scheduled for auto delivery.  Or a SQL agent job that run periodically.

In both cases the an underlying stored procedure needs to be built that queries sysjobs and related tables in MSDB.